# Timeout with sleep PHP not working

Tags: php

I have a cronjob that executes every 22:00 PM.
I get all rows from a table, and for each row I execute a function that execute others.

But one of these functions it's really really slow sometimes and get stuck. So, I need to wait some time and then execute again over and over, to eventually work and I then go to the next row.

I'm trying to use set_time_limit and sleep, but it doesn't work, the function is stuck on the "heavy" function. Why?

```
public function my_job(){
  $rows = get_rows();
  foreach($rows as $row){
     $executed=false;
     while(!$executed){
        set_time_limit(10); // just for test 10s timeout
        if ($this->execute_my_functions($row)){ // this function return true at the end
            $executed = true;
        }
        else{
            sleep(10); // test
        }
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: I would be fixing the function, not trying to make this kind of crazy workaround

Comment: I cant fix the function, because the function access a server that can be slow.